# When will a single iCalendar event have multiple recurrence rules?

Tags: icalendar

I use the ical.NET library for working with iCalendar events in C#.

I noticed that one calendar event can have multiple recurrence rules. When is this the case?

The CalendarEvent class extends the RecurringComponent class, which has this property:

```
public virtual IList<RecurrencePattern> RecurrenceRules { get; set; }
```

Why is this a list? I would think it would be one RecurrencePattern element, not a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely for backward compatibility reasons:

RFC2445 had support for multiple RRULE and EXRULE: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445#section-4.6.1

> ; the following are optional,
> ; and MAY occur more than once

```
            attach / attendee / categories / comment /
            contact / exdate / exrule / rstatus / related /
            resources / rdate / rrule / x-prop
```

RFC5545 which obsoletes RFC2445 removed that feature as it was either not implemented or poorly implemented by most clients. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1

> ;
> ; The following is OPTIONAL,
> ; but SHOULD NOT occur more than once.
> ;
> rrule /

Please note how RFC2445 also had a notion of EXRULE while RFC5545 removed it. Full list of changes at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#appendix-A

Comment: RFC says "EXRULE|Deprecated" but, does it mean it got renamed / replaced? When using iCal.Net 4.1.8 (June 12 - 2018) a serialized calendar contains the following, after using CalendarEvent.ExceptionRules property (Notice EXRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA,SU):

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20181101T141500
DTSTAMP:20180831T183127Z
DTSTART:20181101T131500
EXRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA,SU
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20181201T115959
SEQUENCE:0
UID:1fc3de0a-482f-4902-aa75-ec56d04f04ce
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

Comment: It was removed for lack of support by most clients. Of course, this does not mean that it may not still appear in some piece of code.